# How to extract base with known position

Tags: unix, position, extract, sequence

i have a problem here.

```
Seq1 [organism=Carpodacus mexicanus] C.mexicanus clone
CCTTTATCTTTATCTAGGAGCATGAGCTGGCATAGTTGGAACCGCCCTCAGCCTCCTCATCCGTGCAGAA
CTTGGACAACCTGGAACTCTTCTAGGAGACGACCAAATTTACAATGTAATCGTCACTGCCCACGCCTTCG
TAATAATTTTCTTTATAGTAATACCAATCATGATCGGTGGTTTCGGAAACTGACTAGTCCCACTCATAAT
CGGCGCCCCCGACATAGCATTCCCCCGTATAAACAACATAAGCTTCTGACTACTTCCCCCATCATTTCTT
TTACTTCTAGCATCCTCCACAGTAGAAGCTGGAGCAGGAACAGGGTGAACAGTATATCCCCCTCTCGCTG
GTAACCTAGCCCATGCCGGTGCTTCAGTAGACCTAGCCATCTTCTCCCTCCACTTAGCAGGTGTTTCCTC
TATCCTAGGTGCTATTAACTTTATTACAACCGCCATCAACATAAAACCCCCAACCCTCTCCCAATACCAA
ACCCCCCTATTCGTATGATCAGTCCTTATTACCGCCGTCCTTCTCCTACTCTCTCTCCCAGTCCTCGCTG
CTGGCATTACTATACTACTAACAGACCGAAACCTAAACACTACGTTCTTTGACCCAGCTGGAGGAGGAGA
CCCAGTCCTGTACCAACACCTCTTCTGATTCTTCGGCCATCCAGAAGTCTATATCCTCATTTTAC
```

If i have a fasta file as above (70bases per line), and i wanted to identify what is the base character with position 210th, (Eg: 210th base: T), what's the command line in unix? Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sh
$ tr -d '\n' < mexicanus.fasta | cut -b210
T
```

- remove all newlines from file
- print byte 210

or if you want a range

```sh
$ tr -d '\n' < mexicanus.fasta | cut -b210-220
TCGGCGCCCCC
```

Comment: However, i've slightly modified the code since the fasta file contain header line as well, here there are:


cat mexicanus.fasta | grep -v Seq1 | tr -d '\n' | cut -b210